# FBLoginView not give the email address

Tags: facebook, ios7.1

I have implemented FBLogin for my ios app. and its working fine.
But I want to get the user email address also. But its giving me as null. This is my implementation

In my viewcontroller `Viewdidload`

`btnFbLoging=[[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"]];
    btnFbLoging.delegate=self;`

`

```
 (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                        user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {

NSLog(@"FBName %@",user.name);
NSLog(@"Email %@",[user objectForKey:@"email"]);
```

}
`

I can get the FBName but I cannot get the email. It coming as null
`[3720:60b] Email (null)`

How can I solve this problem. Please help me

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Method name should be:

```
 -(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
```

And this fields are supported

```
user.username
user.first_name
user.last_name]
[user objectForKey:@"email"]
```

Comment: Im sorry that was the method name,, I have made a mistake,,my method name is same as ur one but not giving the email. Whi is that

Comment: Try with other user for test purposes...  may be the problem is with this current user

Comment: I tryed different user too, but still its null. Do I need to set the email public in profile?

Comment: now I set it public and tryed,, but still same. the way Im using is correct? in user array I cant see email keyword.

Comment: @user2889249 have you got any solution for this problem?I am facing same problem too.

Answer (score 0):

All facebook accounts which are verified through ***Phone Number*** instead of email will get `NULL` for `[user objectForKey:@"email"]`